# PyCharm virtual environment Debug Configuration RuntimeError: Can't determine home directory

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.9, pathlib

When running debug configuration debug_app.py in PyCharm I have the error: "RuntimeError: Can't determine home directory". I already checked my home directory is ok.
Can someone helps me to identify the root of the issue and how to fix it? Thanks

```
import lightgbm
File "C:\Users\work\ai_engine\virtuelenv\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .basic import Booster, Dataset, Sequence, register_logger
File "C:\Users\work\ai_engine\virtuelenv\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\basic.py", line 20, in <module>
from .compat import PANDAS_INSTALLED, concat, dt_DataTable, is_dtype_sparse, pd_DataFrame, pd_Series
File "C:\Users\work\ai_engine\virtuelenv\lib\site-packages\lightgbm\compat.py", line 29, in <module>
import matplotlib
File "C:\Users\work\ai_engine\virtuelenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 890, in <module>
dict.update(rcParams, _rc_params_in_file(matplotlib_fname()))
File "C:\Users\work\ai_engine\virtuelenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 567, in matplotlib_fname
for fname in gen_candidates():
File "C:\Users\work\ai_engine\virtuelenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 564, in gen_candidates
yield os.path.join(get_configdir(), 'matplotlibrc')
File "C:\Users\work\ai_engine\virtuelenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 273, in wrapper
ret = func(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\work\ai_engine\virtuelenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 510, in get_configdir
return _get_config_or_cache_dir(_get_xdg_config_dir)
File "C:\Users\work\ai_engine\virtuelenv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 471, in _get_config_or_cache_dir
configdir = Path.home() / ".matplotlib"
File "C:\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 1143, in home
return cls(cls()._flavour.gethomedir(None))
File "C:\Python39\lib\pathlib.py", line 276, in gethomedir
raise RuntimeError("Can't determine home directory")
RuntimeError: Can't determine home directory
```

Comment: This seems to be an error with `pathlib` or `matplotlib` ?